# Leaflet.js tileSize command causes lower half of map to not render

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have created a leaflet map of a fictional map. It all works until I want to set tileSize to 512. Then the lower half of the map won't render on any zoom level larger than 0. All tiles are the size of 512.

The zoom 0 is 512, zoom 1 has 4x 512 tiles.

If I leave the tileSize out (default), then it all renders, however apparently at 256. Which is too small for the purposes I would like it to be. And adding more zoom levels is out of the question, because the original map file is only about 6000 pixels. Which is good for 0,1,2,3 zoom.

```js
    var mymap = L.map("mapid", {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 3,

    }).setView([0, 0], 0);
    L.tileLayer('img/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {


      continousWorld: false,
      noWrap: true,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple,

      tileSize: 512,

    }).addTo(mymap);
```